# -bash: bbb: command not found

Tags: bash, backbone.js

I am trying to go by book:

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#creating-a-new-project

using grunt-bbb.

But cannot make it work. I am using cygwin on windows.

When I run

```
bbb init
```

I get

```
-bash: bbb: command not found
```

Before that I was installing, and if I try to install, it looks that it is ok:

```
$ npm install -g bbb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bbb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bbb
npm WARN package.json bbb@1.0.0-wip No README.md file found!
bbb@1.0.0-wip C:\Users\Darius\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bbb
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: find out where its installed to then add it to your $PATH variable, or execute it with its absolute directory name

Comment: like @marcoms said: `which bbb`, and run with the full path.

Comment: @jerik: `which` won't find it unless it's already in your $PATH.

Comment: Gordon Davisson is correct

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the repository for [grunt-bbb](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb) has been emptied, probably in favor of the [bbb generator](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/generator-bbb) for Yeoman, and the book's examples have not been updated.

Install [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and then do:

```
$ npm install -g generator-bbb
$ yo bbb:app myapp
```

The boilerplate code won't be identical to the book, but should be similar enough to follow along.